# 5.51 GiB already allocated; 417.00 MiB free; 5.53 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch CUDA out of memory

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, torchvision

I am not sure why running this cell throws `CUDA out of memory` error and how I could fix it? Everytime I have to do a `kill -9 PID` from the list of `$ nvidi-smi` jupyter notebook from which this cell is being run. And still after a fresh start I have the same problem.

```
#torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True)
network = Network()
network.cuda()    

criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(network.parameters(), lr=0.0001)

loss_min = np.inf
num_epochs = 10

start_time = time.time()
for epoch in range(1,num_epochs+1):
    
    loss_train = 0
    loss_test = 0
    running_loss = 0
    
    
    network.train()
    print('size of train loader is: ', len(train_loader))

    for step in range(1,len(train_loader)+1):
    
        ##images, landmarks = next(iter(train_loader))
        ##print(type(images))
        
        batch = next(iter(train_loader))
        images, landmarks = batch['image'], batch['landmarks']
        images = images.permute(0,3,1,2)
        
        images = images.cuda()
        
        #RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [64, 3, 7, 7], expected input[64, 600, 800, 3] to have 3 channels, but got 600 channels instead
    
        
    
        landmarks = landmarks.view(landmarks.size(0),-1).cuda() 
        
        print('images shape: ', images.shape)
        print('landmarks shape: ', landmarks.shape)
        
        
        ##images = torchvision.transforms.Normalize(images)
        ##landmarks = torchvision.transforms.Normalize(landmarks)
        
        predictions = network(images)
        
        # clear all the gradients before calculating them
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        
        # find the loss for the current step
        loss_train_step = criterion(predictions.float(), landmarks.float())
        
        print("type(loss_train_step) is: ", type(loss_train_step))
        
        print("loss_train_step.dtype is: ",loss_train_step.dtype)
        
        ##loss_train_step = loss_train_step.to(torch.float32)
        
        # calculate the gradients
        loss_train_step.backward()
        
        # update the parameters
        optimizer.step()
        
        loss_train += loss_train_step.item()
        running_loss = loss_train/step
        
        print_overwrite(step, len(train_loader), running_loss, 'train')
        
    network.eval() 
    with torch.no_grad():
        
        for step in range(1,len(test_loader)+1):
            
            batch = next(iter(train_loader))
            images, landmarks = batch['image'], batch['landmarks']        
            images = images.cuda()
            landmarks = landmarks.view(landmarks.size(0),-1).cuda()
        
            predictions = network(images)

            # find the loss for the current step
            loss_test_step = criterion(predictions, landmarks)

            loss_test += loss_test_step.item()
            running_loss = loss_test/step

            print_overwrite(step, len(test_loader), running_loss, 'Testing')
    
    loss_train /= len(train_loader)
    loss_test /= len(test_loader)
    
    print('\n--------------------------------------------------')
    print('Epoch: {}  Train Loss: {:.4f}  Test Loss: {:.4f}'.format(epoch, loss_train, loss_test))
    print('--------------------------------------------------')
    
    if loss_test < loss_min:
        loss_min = loss_test
        torch.save(network.state_dict(), '../moth_landmarks.pth') 
        print("\nMinimum Test Loss of {:.4f} at epoch {}/{}".format(loss_min, epoch, num_epochs))
        print('Model Saved\n')
     
print('Training Complete')
print("Total Elapsed Time : {} s".format(time.time()-start_time))
```

The complete log is:

```
size of train loader is:  12
images shape:  torch.Size([64, 3, 600, 800])
landmarks shape:  torch.Size([64, 8])

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-efa8f1a4056e> in <module>
     44         ##landmarks = torchvision.transforms.Normalize(landmarks)
     45 
---> 46         predictions = network(images)
     47 
     48         # clear all the gradients before calculating them

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    720             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    721         else:
--> 722             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    723         for hook in itertools.chain(
    724                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

<ipython-input-11-46116d2a7101> in forward(self, x)
     10     def forward(self, x):
     11         x = x.float()
---> 12         out = self.model(x)
     13         return out

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    720             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    721         else:
--> 722             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    723         for hook in itertools.chain(
    724                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/models/resnet.py in forward(self, x)
    218 
    219     def forward(self, x):
--> 220         return self._forward_impl(x)
    221 
    222 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/models/resnet.py in _forward_impl(self, x)
    206         x = self.maxpool(x)
    207 
--> 208         x = self.layer1(x)
    209         x = self.layer2(x)
    210         x = self.layer3(x)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    720             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    721         else:
--> 722             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    723         for hook in itertools.chain(
    724                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py in forward(self, input)
    115     def forward(self, input):
    116         for module in self:
--> 117             input = module(input)
    118         return input
    119 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    720             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    721         else:
--> 722             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    723         for hook in itertools.chain(
    724                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/models/resnet.py in forward(self, x)
     57         identity = x
     58 
---> 59         out = self.conv1(x)
     60         out = self.bn1(out)
     61         out = self.relu(out)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    720             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    721         else:
--> 722             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    723         for hook in itertools.chain(
    724                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py in forward(self, input)
    417 
    418     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 419         return self._conv_forward(input, self.weight)
    420 
    421 class Conv3d(_ConvNd):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py in _conv_forward(self, input, weight)
    414                             _pair(0), self.dilation, self.groups)
    415         return F.conv2d(input, weight, self.bias, self.stride,
--> 416                         self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
    417 
    418     def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:

RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 470.00 MiB (GPU 0; 7.80 GiB total capacity; 5.51 GiB already allocated; 417.00 MiB free; 5.53 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)
```

Here's $ nvidia-smi output right after running this cell:

```
$ nvidia-smi
Tue Oct 13 23:14:01 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.51.06    Driver Version: 450.51.06    CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 2070    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   47C    P8    13W /  N/A |   7609MiB /  7982MiB |      5%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1424      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                733MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1767      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell              426MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      6420      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            2MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      6949      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            2MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      8888      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            2MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     10610      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            2MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     14943      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            2MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     16181      C   ...mona/anaconda3/bin/python     6429MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I have an NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070 GPU.

I also switched these two lines and still no chance and still same error:

```
images = images.permute(0,3,1,2)
images = images.cuda()
```

I also checked the nvidia-smi exactly after running all the cells above this cell, and none of them are causing this CUDA out of memory error.

[image]

Comment: Whenever you face an out of memory issue specially in Jupyter notebooks, first try to restart the runtime, most of the time this solves your issues, specially if you have previously run with smaller batchsizes, the memory is not freed for the duration of runtime and  thus you may pretty much face out of memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the batch_size from 64 to 2 here solved the problem:

```
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=2, shuffle=True, num_workers=4)
```

*Thanks a lot to Sepehr Janghorbani for helping me fix this issue.